# Issue in C++ Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to do some homework and I am running into a problem. My homework is

•Using a for loop, print the contents of the array.

The output should appear like this:

PRINTING CONTENTS OF ARRAY

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

I have my code and it is working. However at the end of my alphabet a bunch of random characters and symbols appear. Is there anything you guys see that I am doing wrong?

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

// main FUNCTION BEGIN PROGRAM EXECUTION
int main()
{
// ALPHABET ARRAY DECLARATIONS
char Letters [26] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};


for (int i = 0; i < 27 ; i++)
{
cout<< "PRINTING CONTENTS OF ARRAY" << endl;
cout<< "===============================" << endl;
cout<< Letters << " ";
cout<< endl;
break;
}
return 0 ;
} // ***END main FUNCTION***
```

Basically the problem to put it simply is that it prints A-Z like I want it to but also prints a bunch of random symbols after Z. Any Ideas? As I am new to this I am sure it's probably something simple.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have an off-by-one error.

Comment: But that's besides the point, right? Jack isn't actually looping. Doesn't the `<<` need a null terminated character array?

Comment: You also have `break;` in there for no reason. You know that breaks the for loop right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the "bunch of random characters and symbols", add a `NUL` to the end of `Letters`:

```
char Letters [] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 
                    'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 
                    'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 0};
```

This is will print the alphabet ***26*** times, which may not be what you want. *Edit:* Previous statement wrong--I missed your `break;`.

Comment: This actually fixed my problem Thank you so much! I switched Letters [26] to [27] added the 0 and it worked like a charm! I appreciate it!

Comment: @Jack How could this possibly fix your problem, if you end up with 27 printouts instead of just one? ;-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, The break statement :(

Comment: @chris Isn't it funny how two wrongs sometimes make a right? The teacher is not going to like this solution, though :)

Comment: I am not sure. I am still new. However when I added the 0 after Z in the array it gave me an error: to many intializer values. I changed the 26 to 27 and it fixed the problem. If I had to guess I would say the 27th null terminated the array as das stated above.                             I will put this as my accepted answer when the 9 minute time ends.

Comment: The `break:` was noted, and answer corrected. But what your teacher probably wants is `for (int i = 0; i < 26 ; i++) cout << 'A' + i; cout << endl;`

Comment: What would you guys suggest to fix it? I would like to get it right programming wise so I know in the future. would I delete the break statement? or what?

Comment: @Jack, Well, the question shows them with spaces in between, so normally, I'd suggest `std::copy`, but that's probably a bit too advanced, so if you want the spaces, you shouldn't worry about the null, or just initialize it with a string literal, and then loop through and print each character, followed by a space. If it's fine without being separated by spaces, the easiest way is to just initialize it to a string literal (which has the null) and then output it as you do in your question, but without the loop.

Answer (score 4):

When you are passing an array of characters to an output stream, the array must be null terminated. Your array is not null terminated; that's why you get extra garbage at the end.

However, this is not the main problem of your solution: you need to *index* letters, like this:

```
cout << Letters[i] << " ";
```

Finally, with 26 letters, indexes go zero to 25, so the loop continuation condition should be `i < 26`, `i != 26`, or `i <= 25`.

Comment: Thank you. Josephs comment showed me how to do what you stated! I appreciate the help!

Comment: Ah I see what you mean! I will check into that and see what happens. I got the desired print out but from what I understand it is still wrong. ^_^

Comment: I made the changes Letters[i] and i < 26 and it simply prints only A now

Comment: @Jack That's because you need to remove the `break`. What happens when you have a `break` is that the loop is effectively gone: it goes through the first iteration, and drops out immediately without going back.

Answer (score 1):

Add a null at the end of array. c functions checks for a null character to terminate.

Answer (score 0):

Array index starts from `0` to `N`, you have 26 characters in Letters, the index starts from `0` to `25`:

```
cout<< "PRINTING CONTENTS OF ARRAY" << endl;
cout<< "===============================" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 26 ; i++)
{
    cout<< Letters[i] << " ";
}
cout<< endl;
```

`break;` is normally used to break `for` or `while` loop under certain condition. You `for` loop`finishes smoothly, you don't need a`break` in the loop.

Comment: Thanks billz, I changed it but it is still giving me the same problem. After Z it is printing a bunch of symbols.

Comment: @Jack, sorry I had typo, I've fixed it

Answer (score 0):

char arrays in C++ are null terminated and starts from zero based index hence when you intialise the array

```
char Letters [26] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
```

You did not take into account that you require 1 more space for '\0' to terminate the array which causes undefined behaviour

Since you print Letters[0] to Letters[26], you are again causing undefined behaviour when you write Letters[26] hence the appearance of rubbish values